# How to display a collection so that all items are visible at once and are taking all available space?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am currently developping a slideshow viewer that should be able to display all of its images in a grid like display. However, this display has the following requirements :

- It should show all items without having to scroll;
- It should be able to handle resizing well (like the Grid control does);

I am using a ListBox, with its ItemPanel set to either WrapPanel or UniformGrid, but they didn't met the requirements : Wrap Panel isn't resizing its items to fill all available space ; UniformGrid gets closer to the desired result, but still leaves an empty space at the end of the last row (ie it should only add a row when it can entirely fill it)

I am therefore looking into a way of setting an UniformGrid so that there's no "blank" left at the end.

As an example, let's say I have three items in my collection, and the actual room to fit them all on one row ; the grid will still creates another row for the third one.

I am also open to solutions for that problem involving other controls, as long as they have a similar behaviour on item resizing and still show all of their items at once.

Thanks

Comment: How would the Grid look like with 17 items (except a single row or column)?

Answer (score 0):

We finally decided to go with a simple wrap with a variable width between items and to just deal with having to scroll if there's too many items.